# Running a python script at at system boot as a daemon

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, daemon

I am attempting to create a daemon that will execute my script at boot.

using this code as my template [Running a python script](http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/)

my python script works interactively when a user is logged in.

```
def wait_for_network():
    while os.system("ping -c 1 8.8.8.8") != 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    return
from getmac import get_mac_address
from datetime import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import time
import random
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import requests 

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.IN)

eth_mac = get_mac_address()
#print(eth_mac)

API_ENDPOINT = "https://xxxxxx.com/handlers/receiveStatus.ashx"
CUSTOMER_KEY = "1234567890"

# Define a callback function that will be called by the GPIO
# event system:
def onButton(channel):
    if channel == 14:
      dt_string = (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])

     data = {'ID':CUSTOMER_KEY, 
            'UUID':str(eth_mac),
            'DT':dt_string,
            'A':str(GPIO.input(6)), 
            'B':str(GPIO.input(24)), 
            'C':str(GPIO.input(23)),
            'D':str(GPIO.input(5))
           } 

r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data) 
#print r.text
#print data

GPIO.add_event_detect(14, GPIO.RISING, callback=onButton, bouncetime=20)

#input()
```

My question is this - **the #input()  do i need it when running as a daemon?**

With it, the script runs until the users presses ctrl-c to break out of.

When I comment it out, the script runs once then returns to the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The GPIO is making a thread and the main thread needs to wait for it.  That was done with the input().  What you can do instead is to make a loop that sleeps instead in place of the input().

```
while True:
   time.sleep(1)
```

That will hold the process from exiting until a ctrl c happens.